# Spring Animation: What does the blendDuration parameter do?

Tags: swiftui

In Apple's definition file for the spring animation is says:

> blendDuration: The duration in seconds over which to interpolate changes to the response value of the spring.

## Code Example

```
struct Spring_BlendDuration: View {
    @State private var change = false
    @State private var blendDuration = 100.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .scaleEffect(change ? 0.2 : 1)
                .animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: blendDuration))
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "hare")
                Slider(value: $blendDuration, in: 0...200)
                Image(systemName: "tortoise")
            }.foregroundColor(.green).padding()
            
            Button("Change") {
                self.change.toggle()
            }.font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

## What it looks like

[image: Animation]

## Comparison with fast Response parameter and slow Response parameter

[image: Comparison]

I'm just not seeing any difference.

### Note

I submitted feedback to Apple to get clarification on this. If I hear back from them, I'll update this question.

Comment: I've never used SwiftUI, but based on a strict interpretation of the documentation you've extracted from the definition file, it doesn't seem like you would see a difference unless the "response" value is also changing (looks to be static in your code). Don't really know what the response value does, though.

Comment: Hey Mark, please check below answer and let me know of it works for you!!

Comment: Blend duration is a frame of time during which previous animation stops and next animation starts. So, at first, it cannot be observed having only one animation, as in your example, at second, it cannot be by time longer than shortest of two animations duration itself even theoretically, because have no sense (in practice probably there might be even shorter limit inside framework implementation of affecting value, say 25%, don't now).

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi. Could you point us to some documentation on this or maybe even an example of how this is used in a practical sense? The goal here is to show how changing the value produces a visual difference. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMoeykens No matter what I try, I just can't get it to look any different!  I think this may be a bug because I feel like I have tried everything, but I'm not exactly sure...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to apply multiple spring() animations to the same property.

```
struct Spring_BlendDuration: View {
    @State private var change = false
    @State private var secondChange = false
    @State private var blendDuration = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .scaleEffect(change ? secondChange ? 0.1 : 0.3 : secondChange ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                .animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.1, blendDuration: blendDuration), value: change)
                .animation(.spring(response: 10, dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: blendDuration), value: secondChange)

             HStack {
                Image(systemName: "hare")
                Slider(value: $blendDuration, in: 0...2)
                Image(systemName: "tortoise")
            }.foregroundColor(.green).padding()

            Text("\(self.blendDuration)")

            Button("Change") {
                withAnimation{
                    self.change.toggle()}
            }.font(.title)

            Button("SecondChange") {
                withAnimation{
                    self.secondChange.toggle()}
            }.font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

If you clicked the other button before a spring animation is over,  you may notice some differences when blendDuration is applied. For example, the circle can expand very large easily compared to the situation without blendDuration.

According to the document:

> A persistent spring animation. When mixed with other `spring()`
>   or `interactiveSpring()` animations on the same property, each
>   animation will be replaced by their successor, preserving
>   velocity from one animation to the next. Optionally blends the
>   response values between springs over a time period.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not show a comparable difference. To test, duplicate that Circle view with all the modifiers so you have one above the other. For the top circle, hard code the blendDuration to 1. For the second circle, hard code the blendDuration to 2000. Then use your change buttons and you'll notice they behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently blendDuration makes no visual change according to this spring animations sample project.

> Changing the blend duration of any of the examples in this repository, does not produce any visual change.

> blend duration has no visible effect on the spring, at the time of writing this article.

https://github.com/GetStream/swiftui-spring-animations